# Symfony - Call to a member function getDestination() on string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

In my Symfony project I am returning all objects with Doctrine query builder defined with *Paginator*.

When dumping `$posts['data']`, response is on the image: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjKTA.png)

When entering the loop and dumping first result, this is what I get: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkrVb.png)

I want on each array object to assign new `key-value` pair. Every array object has **destinationId** (you can see on the image), and I have a method that searches for the name by that param.
I want to assign that new value to every object in foreach.

Code:

```
$posts = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Post::class)->getPage();

foreach ($posts['data'] as $postsData) {
    foreach ($postsData as $post) {
        $destinationName =  $this->destinationService->getDestinationNameById(
            $post->getDestinationId()
        );
        $postsData['destinationName'] = $destinationName;
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
Call to a member function getDestinationId() on string
```

This is very odd as this field has entity type defined as string and also when dumping

```
dump($post->getDestinationId());
```

I get: **"107869901061558"** which is string.

Comment: Try to dump each `$post` to look what's inside, juste before `$destinationName =  $this...`

Comment: I did. And there is array object like on image no. 2, but without [0] :) @jean-max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you override you `$postsData` variable.
You need to use a different variable to store your `$destinationName` like this :

```
$posts = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Post::class)->getPage();
$destinationNames = [];

foreach ($posts['data'] as $postsData) {
  foreach ($postsData as $post) {
    $destinationName =  $this->destinationService->getDestinationNameById(
      $post->getDestinationId()
    );
    $destinationNames[$post->getId()] = $destinationName;
  }
}
```

Like this, you could send `$destinationNames` to your template and find the right `$destinationName` thanks to the index.